# RStudio tag addition

Tags: discussion, tags

I found myself asking an RStudio specific question. The question is more about how a function works within the infrastructure of the software as opposed to general use of R or of the package (Seurat). My issue is RStudio specific.

This tag could be useful for local RStudio sessions, RStudio server sessions, and RStudio cloud sessions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have anything against creating the tag, but I question whether this would be the most relevant forum for such a question. If RStudio is behaving in a very different manner then I'd think asking in their forums is a better tack. In the more likely scenario that RStudio isn't actually doing anything fundamentally different and instead this is yet another "how does Seurat do X" question then it'd be a better fit here.

Comment: I thought it'd be good to ask here because it's not just a tech support "RStudio crashes" kind of question--I think getting the answer requires looking at Seurat and the specific function and determining how its running and what could be tripping up the software in this specific environment. That said I have posted on the RStudio community forums to seek help, and haven't gotten any hits on the question.